# BigDecimal comparison value when decimals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm storing data with a numeric type in a postgresql database

```
CREATE TABLE public.subscriptions (
    amount numeric(15,2)
)
```

But when I use this amount, in a BigDecimal format, to compare it to its own value, in a float format, it fails in some cases. Unless I multiply it to avoid the decimals:

```rb
subscription.amount == 521.18 #=> false
subscription.amount * 100 == 52118 #=> true
```

It seems that the BigDecimal format is the issue here (but I'm not sure it's exactly the same case)

```rb
BigDecimal(52118)/100 == 521.18 #=> false
BigDecimal(52117)/100 == 521.17 #=> true

BigDecimal(52118) == 52118 #=> true
BigDecimal(52117) == 52117 #=> true
```

Do you know what is the explanation of this ? Should I then avoid comparing BigDecimal numbers with float numbers containing decimals ?

Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: "*Should I then avoid comparing BigDecimal numbers with float numbers*" - yes

Comment: Decimal/Numeric types where created as float types have accuracy issues per [Float](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT): "Inexact means that some values cannot be converted exactly to the internal format and are stored as approximations, so that storing and retrieving a value might show slight discrepancies." So comparing a type that is exact to one that can be inexact is going to cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is an issue with the float, not the decimal:

```
irb(main):009:0> 100 * 521.18 == 52118
=> false
irb(main):010:0> 100 * 521.18
=> 52117.99999999999
```

Float imprecision is the whole reason BigDecimals exist.  Converting the float before the comparison will work too:

```
irb(main):014:0> "521.18".to_d == 521.18.to_d
=> true
```